# how to populate two dropdowns with one ajax call returning list inside list

Tags: jquery

this might sound or look like if it has been asked already.
but its different i have one ajax call returning list inside list and one is parent list inside which child list is coming now i want to populate child list drop down based on the selected value of parent drop down select box
this is my code

```
 function populateViolationDropDown() {
           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/controller/getViolations",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                   
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#ViolationTypeID').empty();

                    data.forEach(function (e, i) {
                        $('#ViolationID').append($('<option></option>').val(e.ViolationID).text(e.Description));
                    });
                   
                }
            });
        }
```

this is the data that i am getting

```
    0:
Description: "Punctuality and Regularity"
SubViolationList: Array(3)
0: {SubViolationID: 1, Description: "Appearing For Your Tests"}
1: {SubViolationID: 2, Description: "Appearing For Your Exams"}
2: {SubViolationID: 3, Description: "Homework On Time"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
ViolationID: 1
__proto__: Object
1:
Description: "Personal Appearance and Healthy Habits"
SubViolationList: Array(3)
0: {SubViolationID: 4, Description: "Hair Properly Cut"}
1: {SubViolationID: 5, Description: "Polished Shoes"}
2: {SubViolationID: 6, Description: "Clean School Attire"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
ViolationID: 2
__proto__: Object
2: {ViolationID: 3, SubViolationList: Array(3), Description: "Mannersand Courtesy"}
3: {ViolationID: 4, SubViolationList: Array(3), Description: "Interpersonal and CommunicationSkills"}
```

as you can see i have violation and subviolation list now i want to populate subviolation drop down based on value selected in violation drop down
yes i can send another ajax call and pass it violation type id and get subviolations but i want to do this in one ajax call i am already getting data from controller as shown but can't think of any logic how to populate subviolation dropdown based on value selected in violation dropdown

Comment: Note when you post data to post a JSON formatted version not what you copy from console. The console copy is not valid to run code against and requires a lot of manipulation to make it usable

Answer (score 0):

I created a `$.fakeAjax()` method that you can interchange with regular `$.ajax` which also returns a promise and allows using `then()` instead of `success`.

Inside the `then()` it stores the response data in a variable within `populateViolationDropDown()` to allow using `Array#find()` to get the associated sub violations

```js
$.fakeAjax = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(violationData);
    });
};

populateViolationDropDown()

function populateViolationDropDown() {
    let violationData;// stores data after ajax completes

    const $violSelect = $('#ViolationID'),
        $subViolSelect = $('#SubViolationID');
        
    const request = $.fakeAjax({
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'json',
      data:{}
    })    

    request.then(function (data) {
        violationData = data;// store the data
        const violationOptions = mapOptions('violations', data);
        $violSelect.html(violationOptions)
    }).catch(err=>console.log('Ooops request failed'));

    $violSelect.on('change', function (e) {
        const violationId = Number(this.value);
        const violationObj = violationData.find(function (o) {
            return o.ViolationID === violationId
        });
        const subViolOptions = mapOptions('subviolations', violationObj.SubViolationList);
        $subViolSelect.html(subViolOptions);
    })

}
// helper function to create <option> elemnts from arrays
function mapOptions(type, arr) {
    const opts = arr.map(function(o) {
        const id = type === 'violations' ? o.ViolationID : o.SubViolationID;
        return new Option(o.Description, id)
    });
    
    opts.unshift(new Option(' -- ' + type + ' --',''));
    return opts
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
const violationData = [
    {
        ViolationID: 1,
        Description: "Punctuality and Regularity",
        SubViolationList: [
            { SubViolationID: 1, Description: "Appearing For Your Tests" },
            { SubViolationID: 2, Description: "Appearing For Your Exams" },
            { SubViolationID: 3, Description: "Homework On Time" }
        ]
    },
    {
        ViolationID: 2,
        Description: "Personal Appearance and Healthy Habits",
        SubViolationList: [
            { SubViolationID: 4, Description: "Hair Properly Cut" },
            { SubViolationID: 5, Description: "Polished Shoes" },
            { SubViolationID: 6, Description: "Clean School Attire" }
        ]
    }
]

</script>

Violations: <select id="ViolationID"></select><br/><br/>
Sub Violations: <select id="SubViolationID"></select>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer and also for providing running code snippet

Comment: its giving exception violationdata is not defined in    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                res(violationData);